# Haskell - [Int] -> String

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there an easy way to  change `[Int] -> String` ?
My output function returns a list of int but the format should be a string as in the example below

example: `[1,2,3,4] -> 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell int list to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324621/haskell-int-list-to-string)

Comment: @PRVS That one does more work, also involving non-base-10 representations.

Comment: What do you mean with *change*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn an integer into a string, use `show`.

To turn a list of integers into a list of strings, use `map show`.

To add `" "` between every string in a list of strings, use `intersperse " "`. (Requires `import Data.List`)

To concatenate a list of strings, use `concat`.

Alternative: try `unwords ["a","b","c"]` in GHCi.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I was unsure what to do after map show, but you made it clear enough. Thumbs up!